# Is there a way to replaceMany() with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Suppose I have a collection and a filter that matches three documents in that collection: A,B and C.

I'm looking for an operation that will atomically replace these documents with another set that I will specify. Essentially:

```
collection.find(filter) -> {A,B,C}
collection.replaceMany(filter, {C,D})
collection.find(filter) -> {C,D}
```

A and B have been deleted, and D has been inserted. C could have been changed.

Is there any such operation in MongoDB? If not how would you implement such an operation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153662/discussion-on-question-by-static-rtti-is-there-a-way-to-replacemany-with-mongo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are replacing 3 documents with 2 documents. So it is not replacing documents, it deleting and inserting documents based on some criterias. Deleting and inserting here is separate operations. Both operations take mongodb write lock on **collection**, but these are separate operations as I said earlier.

Your concern is deleting but can't inserting new documents I believe. Your solution is using [bulk write operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/). Or you can always write a rollback mechanism on application level.

Comment: OK, that's what I was expecting. The operation I'm looking for doesn't exist as it is, but can be created by composing existing ones. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @static_rtti happy to help.

Comment: What if I want to replace the 3 documents after I've changed one property in each of them. No insertions or deletions - same document structure even. Still not possible?